# the correct order of manual install WP and SSL on server

Tags: installation, ssl

I am wundering what the correct order of these next things is when you want to manually install Wordpress and have SSL installed on your server and website.
Is this the correct order to do that in?

1. Install SSL certificate for the site on the server
2. Manually install WordPress
3. Go to your website and do all the WP settings for SSL

And what if you don't do it in this order?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's not a correct order. Either way will work and results in a WordPress install that is secured with SSL. What makes sense in a situation, depends on the setup and workflow.

If you can plan ahead, it's optimal to set up the SSL on your server first. Because doing so, you don't have to go back through WordPress, and change settings and the database. In short, you're saving yourself work and avoid potential sources of errors.

Comment: So you're telling me that I should use an auto-installer like Installatron and, to be extra sure, I should ditch the SSL part. Thanks.

Comment: No. That's not what I said at all.

Comment: Just kidding :) Will do it in the order I mentioned then, thanks.

Comment: haha. I'm a robot...I do not know humor.  :)